# How to use notranslate in Google Translate text file

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

How to tell Google to not translate some text file in a text file? This is my sample text file:

> "hp1": "Swipe to the right to reveal the left menu.",
>           "hp2": "(On desktop click and drag from left to right)",
>           "ht": "Welcome",
>           "TITLE": "Welcome",
>           "name":"Gowrisankar Reddy"

google converting above one like this

> "hp1": "ఎడమ మెనుని బహిర్గతం చేయడానికి కుడివైపుకు స్వైప్ చేయండి.",
>   "hp2": "(డెస్క్టాప్ క్లిక్ చేసి ఎడమ నుండి కుడికి లాగండి)",
>   "ht": "స్వాగతం",
>   "TITLE": "స్వాగతం",
>   "పేరు": "గౌరీశంకర్ రెడ్డి"

I don't want to convert `"name"`. How can I do that?

I am not using HTML, using text file only.

Thanks.

Comment: Please find url " https://translate.google.com/#fr/te/%22hp1%22%3A%20%22Swipe%20to%20the%20right%20to%20reveal%20the%20left%20menu.%22%2C%0A%09%09%22hp2%22%3A%20%22(On%20desktop%20click%20and%20drag%20from%20left%20to%20right)%22%2C%0A%09%09%22ht%22%3A%20%22Welcome%22%2C%0A%09%09%22TITLE%22%3A%20%22Welcome%22%2C%0A%09%09%22name%22%3A%22Gowrisankar%20Reddy%22"

Answer (score 1):

> > I am using google translate not used any code

Google Translator can normally skip translations by HTML tags with class `notranslate`.

But since it has a built-in html parser, as a hack, you can pretend one or more words are a tag.

`<name>` will not get translated

Another hack is to capitalize `NAME`

Comment: But still it displaying tags Please find url "https://translate.google.com/#fr/te/%22hp1%22%3A%20%22Swipe%20to%20the%20right%20to%20reveal%20the%20left%20menu.%22%2C%0A%09%09%22hp2%22%3A%20%22(On%20desktop%20click%20and%20drag%20from%20left%20to%20right)%22%2C%0A%09%09%22ht%22%3A%20%22Welcome%22%2C%0A%09%09%22TITLE%22%3A%20%22Welcome%22%2C%0A%09%09%22%3Cname%3E%22%3A%22Gowrisankar%20Reddy%22%22"

Comment: yes and you will have to remove them, there is no way to circumvent that limitation

Comment: Thanks Mr.Attersson. If we mention in capes"NAME" its not converting.Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You are welcome, I wished I knew in advance it would be ok to convert to uppercase and would have been more helpful.